# Экспорт символов из DLL

Tags: c++, dll, export

Скажите, пожалуйста, обязательно ли помечать экспортируемые из разделяемой библиотеки символы?

Я слышал, что `GCC` по умолчанию экспортирует все символы. В то же время, `MSVC` экспортирует только те, которые помечены при помощи перечисления в `DEF`-файле или при помощи `declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: мне кажется, что в вопросе Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: Ну да, все так, для gcc не нужно помечать, для vc нужно

Comment: @KoVadim, у меня нет уверенности в том, что все происходит именно так.